# Spring Data JPA not populating child table in one to many

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "pcSignatureHash": "String",
  "pcSignature": "String",
  "infectedBy": "String",
  "agent": {
    "userCode": 0
  },
  "pc": {
    "name": "String",
    "userName": "String",
    "osType": "String",
    "domainName": "String",
    "cpuId": "String",
    "osVersion": "String",
    "macId": "String",
    "vm": true,
    "friendlyName": "String",
    "statuses": [
      {
        "firewall": true,
        "firewallTestDate": "String"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It's not storing the statuses in the database.

The **infections** has 1 to 1 relationship with **pcs** and pcs has 1 to Many relationship with the **statuses**.

The models are properly set like 1 have `Infections` in `PCs` and have `Set<Statuses>` in the PCs and `Statuses` has `PCs` in its model.

Is there any other way to store the data?
If I store the statuses separately **that doesn't make a sense** it stores the PCs twice because we need to pass the PCs object as a foreign key.

Comment: Can you post the JPA Config (XML) or if you are working with Java Config, the annotated entity classes that are relevant here? I think you just need to set cascading on.

Comment: Can you share your entity classes?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox yes it was cascading I put the cascading on the statuses instead of pcs.

Answer (score 0):

You missunderstood the Relational Mapping. In a OneToMany Relationship you have one side with `@OneToMany` and one with `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: did u put cascade all in parent table ?

Comment: @Ajay my bad, I put the cascading in the child table.

Comment: put cascade in pc entity

Comment: can you share your *entity* files?

Answer (score 0):

Your entities should be like below .
please modify accordingly.

**Cart entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CART")
public class Cart {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="cart_id")
private long id;

@Column(name="total")
private double total;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
private Set<Items> items;

// Getter Setter methods for properties
```

}

**Item Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Items {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="item_id")
private String itemId;

@Column(name="item_total")
private double itemTotal;

@Column(name="quantity")
private int quantity;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
private Cart cart;
// Getter Setter methods for properties
```

}